# Getting error messages trying to play MP3 of podcast episode with a Media Response Fulfillment

Tags: google-cloud-functions, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I’m trying to play an mp3 episode of my podcast, and include the graphic per the instructions on this page regarding Media Responses.
https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/responses#media_responses

The errors have to do with the Cloud Function, per below.

```
    The deployment of your Cloud Function failed:
    Function load error: Code in file index.js can't be loaded.
    Is there a syntax error in your code?
    Detailed stack trace: ReferenceError: conv is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/user_code/index.js:8:6)
    at Module._compile (module.js:577:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:586:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:494:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:453:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:445:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:504:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at getUserFunction (/var/tmp/worker/worker.js:391:24)
    at loadUserCode (/var/tmp/worker/worker.js:447:18)
```

I’m new to Actions on Google, and am not sure where to begin troubleshooting this. It’s my understanding that I can call and play this file using the Inline Editor in Fulfillment.

Below is the code I current have in the Inline Editor.

Greatly appreciate any input on where to go from here. 
thanks
doug

```js
'use strict';

const {dialogflow} = require('actions-on-google');
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

const app = dialogflow({debug: true});

if (!conv.surface.capabilities.has('actions.capability.MEDIA_RESPONSE_AUDIO')) {
  conv.ask('Sorry, this device does not support audio playback.');
  return;
}
conv.ask(new MediaObject({
  name: 'The Wiggins Personality Model',
  url: 'https://storage.googleapis.com/voicemarketing-assets02/v01/media/Ep001-VoiceMarketing-WigginsPersonalityModel.mp3',
  description: 'How Clifford Nass used the Wiggins Personality Model for voice.',
  icon: new Image({
    url: 'https://storage.googleapis.com/voicemarketing-assets02/v01/media/Ep001-VoiceMarketing-EpKeyart-1400x933-brain.png',
    alt: 'Media icon',
  }),
}));


app.intent('play.episode', (conv) => {
  const mediaStatus = conv.arguments.get('MEDIA_STATUS');
  let response = 'Unknown media status received.';
  if (mediaStatus && mediaStatus.status === 'FINISHED') {
    response = 'Hope you enjoyed the tunes!';
  }
  conv.ask(response);
});

exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As shown in the stacktrace:

`Detailed stack trace: ReferenceError: conv is not defined`

`conv` as an object only exists within the scope of your `app.intent`, as an object that is part of the callback.

You're making calls to `conv.ask` outside of that scope, as part of the initial webhook setup. Any conversational bits should be encapsulated within `app.intent` so that they only run if a given intent is triggered. Here, you can see that your snippet has been moved to within an intent handler.

```
app.intent('play-media', conv => {
    if (!conv.surface.capabilities.has('actions.capability.MEDIA_RESPONSE_AUDIO')) {
      conv.ask('Sorry, this device does not support audio playback.');
      return;
    }
    conv.ask(new MediaObject({
        name: 'The Wiggins Personality Model',
         url: 'https://storage.googleapis.com/voicemarketing-assets02/v01/media/Ep001-VoiceMarketing-WigginsPersonalityModel.mp3',
         description: 'How Clifford Nass used the Wiggins Personality Model for voice.',
         icon: new Image({
           url: 'https://storage.googleapis.com/voicemarketing-assets02/v01/media/Ep001-VoiceMarketing-EpKeyart-1400x933-brain.png',
           alt: 'Media icon',
         }),
     }));
})
```